# Position and Sizing OS X windows to Exact Pixel Dimentions/Locations

Tags: macos, window, gui

Is there an OS X application and/or system utility that will allow a user (me) to position application windows at exact screen coordinates, as well as size windows to exact pixel dimensions?  I'm going to creating some documentation, and I'd like things to be positioned and sized exactly the same for each screen capture session.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try using an AppleScript to set the window size and position.

You could do something similar to:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set the bounds of the first window to {100, 0, 1000, 700}
end tell
```

You could also set size and position of subsequent windows using 'second window'.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

[MercuryMover](http://www.heliumfoot.com/mercurymover/) is a shareware System Preferences module close to what you want. I bought it a while back and use it all day, everyday. It lets you move and resize windows using the keyboard, and gives you an overlay telling you where the window is with co-ordinates. You may also want to write a little AppleScript as per JT.WK's suggestion ([more details here](http://www.ithug.com/2007/09/applescript-moving-and-resizing-windows/)).